# Is there anyway to get the list of URLs in all div's in the same class?

Tags: python, html

I am trying to get the URLs of all the classes in the website and putting them into a Google Sheets. It is able to gather the info I want from the first class, but I would like it to get all the other classes as well. An example of the HTML of the page is below:

```
<div class="list-pages-item">
<p><a href="/abyssal-angel-ac">Abyssal Angel (AC)</a></p>

<div class="list-pages-item">
<p><a href="/acolyte">Acolyte</a></p>

<div class="list-pages-item">
<p><a href="/alpha-omega-non-legend">Alpha Omega (Non-Legend)</a></p>
```

As you can see there is not much identification between the div classes and I am trying to get the text (Name of the class) and the URL (href). I have the follwing code for pulling the classes.

```
def parse(soup):
    #Grabs Classes
    htmlcode = soup.find('div', class_='list-pages-item')
    base_url = "http://aqwwiki.wikidot.com"
    ClassName = htmlcode.text.strip()
    for a in htmlcode.find_all('a', href=True):
        wiki = (base_url + a['href'])
    Outcome = {'Class': ClassName, 'URL': wiki}
    return Outcome
```

Is there a way to make a loop to repeat the process but grabbing the next div instead? Or is there a more efficient way of doing this process?

I am using bs4 and am in Python 3.

Comment: `</div>` are missing.

Comment: Yeah, had to edit or else each one will look like this:
```
<div class="list-pages-item">


<p><a href="/abyssal-angel-ac">Abyssal Angel (AC)</a></p>
<img src="http://aqwwiki.wdfiles.com/local--files/image-tags/acsmall.png" alt="acsmall.png" class="image"><span style="white-space: pre-wrap;"> </span><img src="http://aqwwiki.wdfiles.com/local--files/image-tags/raresmall.png" alt="raresmall.png" class="image"><span style="white-space: pre-wrap;"> </span></div>
```